# Cannot load css from route

Tags: css, routes

I'm using FatFree Framework. When I create a page with F3 it work fine. The page is loaded with css & js and has a nice look.

/index.php

```
<?php

 $f3 = require('f3/lib/base.php');

 $f3->route('GET /post',
   function($f3) {
     echo \Template::instance()->render('./view/post.htm');
   }
 );
```

When I try to load post with specific id, the page looks like it did not load css properly (messy).

```
$f3->route('GET /post/@id',
   function($f3,$params) {
     $postid = $params['id'];
     echo \Template::instance()->render('./view/post.htm');
   }
 )
```

/view/post.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <include href="./template/head.htm" />
  <body>
    {{ post: $id }}
  </body>
</html>
```

/template/head.htm

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="">

<!-- Document title -->
<title> Post </title>
<link rel="icon" href="./img/logo/logo-ftn-16x18.jpg" />

<!-- Stylesheets & Fonts -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,800,700,600|Montserrat:400,500,600,700|Raleway:100,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Template color -->
<link href="./css/color-variations/orange.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the CSS' location wrong. `./` means, you want to load the css content from within the current "folder" or route you're currently at. If you open "example.com/post/123", the browser tries to load your CSS from "example.com/post/123/css/style.css".

Change your path to `/` instead, which means the CSS will load from "example.com/css/style.css".

Also: this has nothing to do with the PHP framework you use.